# This jquery method is not working when i called ajax function in another ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, html

it gives error like this in console.

> XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/redono/Redono-ChurchAdmin/code/churchprofile/edit_password".

Here I want to create the change password method.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "churchprofile/edit_password",
  data: {
    password: oldByUser
  },
  success: function(data) {
    if (data == 'pass') {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "churchprofile/update_password",
        data: {
          new_password: new_password
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == 'changed') {
            alert("success");
          } else if (data == 'failed') {
            alert("failed");
          } else {
            alert("try again later");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: *it gives error like this in console.* - Can you give the exact error at least?

Comment: XHR finished loading: POST "http://localhost/redono/Redono-ChurchAdmin/code/churchprofile/edit_password"

Comment: What is to stop someone from just posting to the second script? If this is supposed to increase security by asking for the current password on a password change, it is not. Why are you making 2 requests for this?

Comment: i can not understand your meaning @jeroen

Comment: It's very odd that you're making two API calls for this. I'd suggest having an 'edit' endpoint that accepts both the old password (to verify it) and the new one (so the change can be made if the old password was valid);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Try this ,Its working for me.
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/churchprofile/edit_password",
  data: {
    password: oldByUser
  },
  success: function(data) {
    if (data == 'pass') {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/churchprofile/update_password",
        data: {
          new_password: new_password
        },
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == 'changed') {
            alert("success");
          } else if (data == 'failed') {
            alert("failed");
          } else {
            alert("try again later");
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```